# Generate Azure Storage Account SAS Key using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, azure-storage-account, azure-sas

I am trying to generate an azure storage account shared access key so that i can use it with azcopy to retrieve files from all containers in my storage account.

I have generated a key successfully using the Azure Portal and proven this works with azcopy

But i am struggling to get an equivalent key to generate using PowerShell that works.

**Powershell Query**
`az storage container generate-sas --account-name $SaName --account-key $accountKey --permissions 'rl' --start $start --expiry $expiry --name $SaName --https-only  --output tsv`

**Azure Portal (GUI) Result**

```
sv=2019-12-12
&ss=b
&srt=sco
&sp=rl
&se=2021-02-08T17:40:26Z
&st=2021-02-08T09:40:26Z
&spr=https
&sig=REDACTED
```

**Powershell Result**

```
st=2021-02-08T17%3A17%3A47Z
&se=2021-02-08T17%3A47%3A47Z
&sp=rl
&spr=https
&sv=2018-11-09
&sr=c
&sig=REDACTED
```

I guess the first problem is that i have not found a way of adding the missing and ss=b srt=sco (not sr) there doesn't seem to be those parameters available, perhaps if they were there the sig would have the correct hash.

I have tried this in Azure Cloudshell as well as on my own machine with az 1.12.1

Comment: It looks like the first example in the built in Help for `New-AzStorageAccountSASToken` shows how to make an account level token. Have you tried that already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command [az storage container generate-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_container_generate_sas) is not powershell command, it's [azure cli command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli).

Because in Azure portal, you're generating an `account level sas-token`, but in azure cli, you're actually generating a `container level sas-token` by using [az storage container generate-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_container_generate_sas).

To generate an `account level sas-token`, you should use this azure cli command: [az storage account generate-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_generate_sas).

The sample like below:

```
az storage account generate-sas --account-key "xxxxx"  --account-name your_storage_account_name --expiry 2020-02-10 --https-only --permissions rl --resource-types sco --services b
```

Here is the test result, the `ss=b srt=sco` are generated:

[image]

**If you want to use powershell** to generate an `account level sas-token`, please use this powershell command: [New-AzStorageAccountSASToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageaccountsastoken?view=azps-5.4.0). The sample is as below(you can add other parameters as per your need):

```
$account_name = "yy1"

$account_key = "xxxxxxx"

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $account_name -StorageAccountKey $account_key

#you can also add other parameter as per your need, like StartTime, ExpiryTime etc.
New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Service Blob -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission rl -Context $context
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks az storage account generate-sas works.  For information you can run az commands in a powershell session on Windows f you have the az module installed like i have but  in runtime this will be run from an Azure Function