Why is a Azure VM snapshot 0 bytes in size when copied to a storage account in Azure?
I make a snapshot of a VM and copy to a storage account , but it is 0 bytes in size
i copy to storage account using:
        az storage blob copy start --account-name $storageAccountName --destination-blob    $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName  --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas

the problem is that it is 0 bytes in size
UPDATE:
I am using the following
#Provide the subscription Id where snapshot is created
subscriptionId="<subscriptionId>"

   #Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot is created
   resourceGroupName=myResourceGroupName

   #Provide the snapshot name 
   snapshotName=mySnapshotName

   #Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds 
   e.g. 3600.
   #Know more about SAS here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en- 
  us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
   sasExpiryDuration=3600

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the snapshot. 
storageAccountName=mystorageaccountname

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded snapshot will be stored
   storageContainerName=mystoragecontainername

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy snapshot. 
storageAccountKey=mystorageaccountkey

#Provide the name of the VHD file to which snapshot will be copied.
destinationVHDFileName=myvhdfilename

az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

az storage blob copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas


But i get the error:

     0.0244%ERROR: The condition specified using HTTP conditional header(s) is not met.


I have tried that . The issue is that the copy to storage is always as "failed" and how will i know when it is successful . Do i need to put the status check in a loop until "success"

How much your snapshot size?

you can use of loop untill it get successful.

my snapshot is about 256G .  I waited about 28hrs and still 0 bytes

Why you can't go with azcopy ?

After getting source uri from snap you can use azcopy to from source to blob storage?

what you mean ? do i use azcopy to copy to local drive c:\

is there some working example you can provide?

Check the below answer.


I have tried that. The issue is that the copy to storage always shows as "failed," and I don't know when it is successful. Do I need to put the status check in a loop until "success"?

You can use the script below until the copy status succeeds; it will run in your environment.
Script:
resourceGroupName="xxxx"
snapshotName="xxx"
sasExpiryDuration=3600
storageAccountName="venkat123"
storageContainerName="test"
storageAccountKey="MnvIVSoYytjs0HEREfTatdvBIRnoYUC2ZJVyIDNqDaBk+Mb/2+QGn50A/sfw0k8yMJad+G9+SrsS+AStxf+aMQ=="
destinationVHDFileName="abcd.vhd"


sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

# Copy snapshot to Azure Storage
copyId=$(az storage blob copy start --account-name $storageAccountName --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas --query id --output tsv)

# Check status of blob copy operation
status=$(az storage blob show --account-name $storageAccountName --container-name $storageContainerName --name $destinationVHDFileName --query properties.copy.status -o tsv --account-key $storageAccountKey)

# Wait for blob copy operation to complete
while [ "$status" != "success" ]
do
    echo "Blob copy operation status: $status"
    sleep 10
    status=$(az storage blob show --account-name $storageAccountName --container-name $storageContainerName --name $destinationVHDFileName --query properties.copy.status -o tsv --account-key $storageAccountKey)
done

echo "Blob copy operation completed successfully."

The above script will execute until the status is copied to succeed.
Output:
Blob copy operation completed successfully.


However, I would suggest you use azcopy because it is faster.
Script:
resourceGroupName="v-vsettu-mindtree"
snapshotName="snap1"
sasExpiryDuration=3600
storageAccountName="venkat123"
storageContainerName="test"
storageAccountKey="MnvIVSoYytjs0HEREfTatdvBIRnoYUC2ZJVyIDNqDaBk+Mb/2+QGn50A/sfw0k8yMJad+G9+SrsS+AStxf+aMQ=="
destinationVHDFileName="abcd.vhd"
sastoken="sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2024-04-12T13:18:23Z&st=2024-04-12T05:18:23Z&spr=https&sig=nt0kh7MMc7dciYbGAYzF9nv5Z1XFR%2B4ARKxYr%2BmssUY%3D"

# Generate SAS token for snapshot
sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $snapshotName --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

# Copy snapshot to Azure Storage using AzCopy
azcopy copy $sas "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$storageContainerName/$destinationVHDFileName?$sastoken" --recursive=true 

echo "Blob copy operation completed successfully."

Output:
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because the source and/or destination don't have full folder support

Job b51597xxxxd285b354 has started
Log file is located at: /home/venkatesan/.azcopy/b51xxxxx4b-58ed-c63bd285b354.log

93.3 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 1 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 3723.9013


Job b515970f-58b1-164b-58ed-c63bd285b354 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.2335
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: xxxx
Final Job Status: Completed

Blob copy operation completed successfully.


After copied to blob storage you can use same azcopy to download to you local environment.
Command:
azcopy copy "https://$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/$storageContainerName/$destinationVHDFileName?$sastoken"  "C:\demo\abcd.vhd" --recursive=true 

It will download to your local environment.
Reference:
azcopy copy | Microsoft Learn
Update:
To generate sas token(windows) uisng CLI you can use the below command:
Command:
az storage account generate-sas --account-key "xxxx"  --account-name "xxx" --expiry (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddHours(2).ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ') --https-only --permissions rl --resource-types sco --services b

Output:
"se=2024-04-14T14%3A19%3A32Z&sp=rl&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&ss=b&srt=sco&sig=WH6rZtxxxxD"



How did you get the sastoken ?

You can get the sas token from portal or through azure cli command refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-generate-sas-examples

Hope this address your issue.

they are for linux and mac os , are you please able to provide me one for windows and what and where i can get the parameter values from . thanks

Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107008/generate-azure-storage-account-sas-key-using-powershell

I keep getting "Final Job Status: Failed" no file is copied to storage account

Add command in question which you have used and add error snippet.

Have you tried with azcopy which I mentioned in answer for larger files?

I have but it seemed to stop half way. But I will try again

Let me know if you found an result.
